# Bright pulsating light

Tags: star, identify-this-object

Was looking at the sky and I see a satellite , turned around and saw another light , but this light was pulsating like a strobe light , definitely not a plane , next thing I know the light goes out and was not seen again , could this be a dying star , I know what satellites and planes look like in the sky , but I have never seen anything like this , it just went dark after being super bright

Comment: Most likely a plane behind clouds.

Answer (score -1):

This might be it:
[Astronomers Say Giant Disco Ball in Space Is Bad for Science](https://gizmodo.com/astronomers-say-giant-disco-ball-in-space-sets-a-bad-pr-1822454265)

Three foot diameter faceted mirror ball launched late January 2018.
I don't know either designation or orbit.

Comment: [Reentered](https://sattrackcam.blogspot.com/2018/03/the-reentry-of-humanity-star.html) 2018-03-22.

Comment: Sorry mysterious downvoter, but a 3 foot faceted spherical mirror would give a pulsating light unless it was non rotating. You are wrong.